# help compiling code for flora project

Tags: c++, compile

I'm working on the Adafruit Firewalker shoes.

I can't make my code compile to test my flora project.

This is my error message:

```
Arduino: 1.6.7 (Windows 10), Board: "Adafruit Flora"

C:\Users\Devi\Documents\Arduino\test_2\test_2.ino\test_2.ino.ino:1:29: fatal error: Adafruit_NeoPixel: No such file or directory


 #include <Adafruit_NeoPixel>

                             ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

---

https://learn.adafruit.com/firewalker-led-sneakers/test-circuit

```C++
    #include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

const int analogInPin = A9;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(10, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP); 
   strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'

}

void loop() {
  // read the analog in value:
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);              
  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  Serial.print("sensor = " );                       
  Serial.println(sensorValue);      

if (sensorValue < 100){
  Serial.println("leds triggered"); 
colorWipe(strip.Color(255, 0, 0), 25);
colorWipe(strip.Color(0, 0, 0), 25);
}  

}

void colorWipe(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait) {
  for(uint16_t i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, c);
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the code, and the error message, into your question as text? Not a screen-shot? I can hardly read what the error is. *Edit* your post and format the code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you.

Comment: @NickGammon thank you sorry I'm a mess ive never coded with Arduino before

Comment: Your error message says `#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel>` but your code says `#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>` - which do you actually have?

Comment: @NickGammon I have #include <adafruit_neopixel.h>  all I did was copy and paste the source code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you just have to download the Adafruit Neo Pixel library:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i think issue is in your this path 
C:\Users\Devi\Documents\Arduino\test_2\test_2.ino\test_2.ino.ino:1:29: fatal error: Adafruit_NeoPixel:

make new arduino file and copy the same code and save it on other folder on desktop or other drive then compile it

**Compilation**
I compiled you same code and my stored path of .ino file is
C:\Users\Muhammad Hassaan\Documents\Arduino\sketch_mar04a

[image]

Comment: this did work it still says no directory found for neopixels did I install something wrong all I did was copy and paste source code

Comment: i think issue is with your library that you have downloaded, please reinstall the Arduino IDE and download the library again with the help of ide then recompile your code